# How can i get value from <h:selectManyCheckbox>

Tags: java, jsf

I have one collection , which I'm displaying in my .xhtml page by `<h:dataTable>`. I want to reach a few goals: at first I want to set  list.check value by `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`, at second I want  whatever the  values remains selected until the end of current session. Now It displays correctly, but when I select some value it doesn't transmit it in list.check property. I'm using JSF v.2.2.

Code in JSF bean:

```
private List<AnswerDTO> answerListDto;
//getters and setters
```

Code in .xhtml

```
<h:form> 
    <h:dataTable value="#{main.answerListDto}" var="list">
        <h:column>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{list.check}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{list.ansValue}" />
            </h:selectManyCheckbox> 
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

AnswerDTO class:

```
public class AnswerDTO implements Serializable, DTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer     id;
    private Question    questId;
    private String      ansValue;
    private String      ansStatus;
    private String      check;    

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange use of `selectManyCheckbox` I must say. Concrete problem is that value of `selectManyCheckbox` must be an array.

My opinion is that `selectBooleanCheckbox` should be used instead of `selectManyCheckbox`. Your `check` property can have only two values, an empty array (if checkbox is not selected), and array of length 1 with value which is equal to `ansValue` (if checkbox is selected).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've changed manyCheckBox on booleanCheckBox, and set list.check boolean type, but list.check still empty :(

Comment: You removed the `selectItem` tag?

Comment: Now it looks like this: <h:column>
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxAnswer"  value="#{list.check}"/>
      <h:outputText value="#{list.ansValue}"/>
     </h:column>

Comment: With this code you will have collision with ids, I doubt this is rendered?

Comment: I've resolved my promblem. Thank you for your efforts,but the source of all my problems was my stupidity. Your advice about selectBooleanCheckbox was very useful